# How to set number picker value from dialog to button

Tags: android, button, dialog, numberpicker

I have `ListView` .In `ListView`, for every row (adapter) I have one `Button` . On button click I opened one dialog. This dialog contain Number picker.
I want to set number pickers selected value on same button. and also I want this changes only for that particular row.

Please see my code and help me.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //showDialog();
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
            d.setTitle("Select Repeat Value ");
            d.setContentView(R.layout.numberpicker_layout);
            //Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            //Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            final android.widget.NumberPicker np = (android.widget.NumberPicker)d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
            np.setMaxValue(100); // max value 100
            np.setMinValue(0);   // min value 0
            np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
            np.setOnValueChangedListener(new android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(android.widget.NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                    scrollValue=newVal;
                    repeatNo=newVal;
                }
            });
            np.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Scroll value",""+scrollValue);
                    //setValue(scrollValue);
                    button1.setText(String.valueOf(scrollValue));
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });

            /*b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue())); //set the value to textview
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss(); // dismiss the dialog
                }
            });*/

            index.playIndex(repeatNo);
            d.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OpenNumberPickerDailog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.timer_dailog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        final NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(2);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(15);
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = numberPicker.getValue();
                //int PickedNumber= as * 1000;

                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
```

timer_dailog.xml

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/footer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Select time. "
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#A76EA9"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#A76EA9"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```